# Why is the schedule button missing in Dataprep Starter Edition even though the documentation suggests it's included?

Tags: schedule, google-cloud-dataprep, dataprep

I have Starter Edition of Dataprep on GCP, which based on the documentation (image below), "Schedule and Orchestrate Data Pipelines" is included. However, "Schedule" button doesn't appear for me.

[documentation of editions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmDTc.png)

Is it really possible to schedule pipelines with Starter Edition??? Or the documentation is wrong?

I tried all kinds of contact with support but no answer. I expect that Starter Version has Schedule functionality because that's what is written in the documentation.